# run 2 ajax functions after one another

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to run the showBalance and showTeam functions one after the other. they are first triggered by the a mouse click i.e. the addPlayer function. i want the other two to also execute as well in a chain reaction. at  the moment only 1 of the showBalance/showTeam functions will work at anyone time.

```
function addPlayer(playerID, playerValue) {
  if (ajaxObject.readyState == 4 || ajaxObject.readyState == 0) {
    ajaxObject.open("GET", "http://localhost:8888/FantasyFootball/V3.0/addPlayer.php?playerID=" + playerID + "&playerValue=" + playerValue, true);
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = ajaxObject.responseText;
    ajaxObject.onreadystatechange = showBalance;
    ajaxObject.send();
  }
}

function showBalance() {
  ajaxObject.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (ajaxObject.readyState == 4 && ajaxObject.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = ajaxObject.responseText;
    }
  }
  ajaxObject.open("GET", "http://localhost:8888/FantasyFootball/V3.0/bankBalance.php", false);
  ajaxObject.onreadystatechange = showTeam;
  ajaxObject.send();
}

function showTeam() {
  ajaxObject.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (ajaxObject.readyState == 4 && ajaxObject.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("playerFormation").innerHTML = ajaxObject.responseText;
    }
  }
  ajaxObject.open("GET", "http://localhost:8888/FantasyFootball/V3.0/showSquad.php", false);
  ajaxObject.send();
}
```

Comment: Do you think it has something to do with using the same global variables all over the place ?

Comment: @adeneo That was my first thought, too. But since they're sequential, not parallel, it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`showBalance()` was doing its readystate checks inside another `onreadystatechange` handler, and was setting this handler twice. It should just check them directly, and then set up the handler for the next AJAX call.

```
function showBalance() {
  if (ajaxObject.readyState == 4 && ajaxObject.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = ajaxObject.responseText;
      ajaxObject.open("GET", "http://localhost:8888/FantasyFootball/V3.0/bankBalance.php", false);
      ajaxObject.onreadystatechange = showTeam;
      ajaxObject.send();
  }
}

function showTeam() {
  if (ajaxObject.readyState == 4 && ajaxObject.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("playerFormation").innerHTML = ajaxObject.responseText;
      ajaxObject.open("GET", "http://localhost:8888/FantasyFootball/V3.0/showSquad.php", false);
      ajaxObject.onreadystatechange = showSquad; // I'm just guessing
      ajaxObject.send();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but im still having a few problems in the form of this error in google chrome    Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. I've removed the onreadystatechange from the showTeam function because i dont what it to do anything else after the team is displayed

Comment: Then you need to set `onreadystatechange` to null, otherwise it will try to call `showTeam` again.

Comment: Or you could use a different AJAX object for each step.

Comment: if i was to use two separate AJAX objects would i only have to change the ajaxObject in one of the functions to say ajaxObject2 for example? or would i have to reference the new object in the other function?

Comment: You would create `ajaxObject2` the function that starts the second AJAX call, and then reference it again in the `onreadystatechange` handler to get the state and status.